# Meteor.js : .find() returns nothing even though the database is not empty

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So I'm making a pretty simple web app and I am currently trying to use a database in it.
However, even though I create the collection, then make the appropriate helper, when I try to use it nothing seems to be rendering. So I went into console and tried to see what Unis.find().fetch() would return (Unis being my collection), and it returns an empty array, so that explains why nothing is rendering. However, when using the mongo command prompt I can find items as well as insert them. I am really confused as to what might be happening.

My JavaScript related to the collection, so the helper for my template and defining the collection:

```
    Unis = new Mongo.Collection("unis");

    if (Meteor.isClient) {
      // Rendering
      Template.dashboard.helpers({
        unis: function() {
          return Unis.find();
        }
      });
    }

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
      });
    }
```

HTML for using the collection, but I don't think this is the problem here

```
<template name="dashboard">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    {{#each unis}}
      {{> uni}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>

</template>

<template name="uni">
  {{name}}
</template>
```

Using Unis.find().fetch(); doesn't return anything but it does in mongo
[image: Using Unis.find().fetch(); doesn't return anything but it does in mongo]

Any help would be really appreciated, as I don't have much of an idea what to do. I am also new to Meteor, so not sure if this is really obvious or not.

EDIT: Added actual code instead of pictures.

Comment: Can you please try to include the actual code in your question instead of images because code in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem. Among many other reasons why it's not generally recommended to post images of code here on SO, images are large and hard to read on mobile devices, they can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers.

Comment: Is it possible you did not publish anything? can you please add your Meteor.publish code to the question?

Comment: @chrisdam Sorry about that, I didn't really think about it, edited the main post to include the code itself.

Comment: @ErezHochman I don't really have any Meteor.publish code, so maybe that's it? Though I haven't removed autopublish so I shouldn't have to... right? I just followed Meteor's To-Do List Tutorial thing in a separate project and it worked without having to do any Meteor.publish, so that's why I didn't do anything in my main project as well.

Comment: Can you run `meteor list` just to make sure you have autopublish?

Comment: @StephenWoods I just did, and Autopublish is there, version 1.0.4

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and it was a very obvious mistake, just I failed to disclose important information.
The JavaScript I posted was in "website.js" in "client" folder inside my directory, so it was only getting defined on the client.
I simply just made a "shared.js" on the root of my directory and put that line in there and done!
Still thank you all for your replies!